# Error: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet and dateAccessed is unknown column

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am executing below query in spring MVC JAVA

```
if (currentFireTime != null && previousFireTime != null) {
        timePart = " sal.dateAccessed between '" + previousFireTime + "' and '" + currentFireTime + "' and ";
    }
    String queryString = " select count(*) as COUNT FROM LogData sal where " + timePart + " sal.userSigned = false and sal.batchMetaDataId = "+batchId;
    SQLQuery sq =sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(queryString);
    sq.addScalar("COUNT", IntegerType.INSTANCE);
    sq.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
    List<Map<String,Object>> resultSet=sq.list();
    return (Integer)resultSet.get(0).get("COUNT");
```

When executed looks like this and putting this in Mysql it works fine. But i get error as shown below.

```
select count(*) as COUNT FROM LogData sal where sal.dateAccessed between '2016-12-26 00:00:00.618' and '2016-12-26 01:00:00.618' and  sal.userSigned = false and sal.batchMetaDataId = 86
```

error shown

```
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
```

What should i need to change in shown code?

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching count in wrong way. Try this:

```
resultSet.getInt("COUNT");
```

Comment: I am getting error in 2nd line and gives error  sal.dateAccessed is unknown column.

Comment: @daisy which is line number 2??

Comment: @SachinSarawgi  Line two is  timePart = " sal.dateAccessed between '" + previousFireTime + "' and '" + currentFireTime + "' and ";

Comment: @daisy could you try the same query without `sal.` thing. Because its one table only so their will be no confusion.